# Why I need sometimes to run `build` before `package`?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, maven-compiler-plugin

Sometimes the `maven` phase `package` fails, not seeing some symbols in the project. What is interesting, they needn't be new symbols or be called from new classes. They are not generated ones. They are some classes from our project and some from dependent libraries. Obviously, imports didn't work...

After pressing IntelliJIdea `build` button and waiting for the build, I can run `package` successfully.

AFAIK, if I call the `package` phase, all phases before it are called sequentially. So, all previous building should be done among other previous phases when I call `package`.

Why is it not done?
What special important thingies does that build IntelliJIdea button do?
How can I include all needed building into `package` call?

Comment: You might oversight compile errors in the log?

Comment: Why are you running "mvn package" instead of your build bot?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What exactly do you mean by a "build bot"?

Comment: @JFMeier I guess you know the answer already to that question.  An automated system which runs maven on the sources in a controlled environment.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I was not sure if you are referring to a special tool or something. I understand that this would be a useful thing to have, but I know that is not common everywhere. If you have trunk-based svn development without any branches, you often don't want every commit to be a build.

Comment: @JFMeier If you still do trunk-based developing using svn, that is a bigger problem that needs to be fixed first.  Any of mercurial, bazaar or git will do, but please migrate.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Agreed, but change is hard, not only the technical part, but more the workflow part. Many developers will struggle with (and not like) something like gitflow and we'll need to convince them. Committing on trunk is easy to understand and follow, and getting of that habit will be a lot of work...

Comment: What are the symbols which are not found? Are they generated? Does your project have annotation processors? Note that IDE's build action if you do not use Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven** differs from Maven `build` goal - IDE uses it's own [builder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-and-builder.html).

Comment: @Andrey 1. No, they are not generated. They are some classes from our project and some from dependent libraries. Obviously, imports didn't work... The delegation of build to Maven is turned off. Of course. For Maven compiling does not make the imports visible. Inellijidea's build does... The project is stuffed by annotations and they work normally.

Comment: First fix the command line build! You will probably find that a freshly created IntelliJ project with the revised sources will work then.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Then, rather, the incorrect build setting will be in the POM, for it is maven that does not build correctly.

Comment: @gagnus I don’t understand your point. Your maven build should work correctly before you even consider having an IDE on top of it. Given the current situation I would suggest purging your local repository and work with a fresh clone